# ^I character in VI of git bash

Tags: vi, git-bash

I'm running bash of git on Windows.

I copy the text below from http://www.chrismoos.com/2014/05/28/coreos-with-cloud-config-on-vmware-esxi

> ## cloud-config hostname: my-hostname ssh_authorized_keys:
>
> ```
> - ssh-rsa YOUR_KEY_HERE write_files:
> - path: /etc/systemd/network/static.network
>   permissions: 0644
>   content: |
>     [Match]
>     Name=ens33
>
>     [Network]
>     Address=10.0.1.5/24
>     Gateway=10.0.1.1
>     DNS=8.8.8.8
>     DNS=8.8.4.4
> - path: /etc/iptables.rules
>   permissions: 0644
>   content: |
>     *filter
>     :INPUT DROP [0:0]
>     :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
>     :OUTPUT ACCEPT [76:7696]
>     -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m multiport --dports 22 -j ACCEPT
>     -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
>     -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
>     -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
>     -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
>     COMMIT coreos:
> units:
>     - name: systemd-networkd.service
>       command: start
>     - name: iptables.service
>       command: start
>       content: |
>         [Unit]
>         Description=iptables
>         Author=Me
>         After=systemd-networkd.service
>
>         [Service]
>         Type=oneshot
>         ExecStart=/usr/sbin/iptables-restore /etc/iptables.rules
>         ExecReload=/usr/sbin/iptables-restore /etc/iptables.rules
>         ExecStop=/usr/sbin/iptables-restore /etc/iptables.rules
>
>         [Install]
>         WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```

- and paste in VI, It becomes

[image: ^I Character in VI of GIT BASH]

How can i fix it? what is the ^I character?

Comment: I'm not a vi user, but ^I (aka ctrl+I) is another way to type a tab. Might help you figure it out

Answer (score 0):

^I is the tab character.

`:%s/`(type tab key)`/    /g`

should work to replace each tab by 4 spaces.

Comment: Could you show me how to avoid this case? i can't replace anytime I paste

Comment: Try entering `:set paste` in your vi before pasting.

Comment: Can we set it by default?

Comment: Yes, in your .exrc file (or .vimrc if you are using vim)